# Application crashes trying instantiate Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have rare amount of crashes (about 2.5K for the last few months) reported by Google Play Console when App tries to init Firebase Crashlytics but fails to do that and crashes by throwing a RuntimeExcepcption.

What could be an issue? Or just wait for another lib's release? :)
Thanks.

Deps:

```
 "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1"
 "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0"
```

Stack trace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4745)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1407)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5453)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:781)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:671)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull (Objects.java:109)
  at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance (FirebaseCrashlytics.java:232)
  at com.*.MyApplication.onCreate (MyApplication.java:82)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1016)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4741)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1407)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5453)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:781)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:671)
```

Code snippet (just regular init):

```
     @Override
     override fun onCreate() {
         super.onCreate()
         FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
         FirebasePerformance.getInstance()
               .isPerformanceCollectionEnabled = false
         FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()
               .setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG_BUILD_TYPE) // <- line 82
     }
```

Comment: "  at com.*.MyApplication.onCreate (MyApplication.java:82)" The error indicates that the problem occurs on line 82 of MyApplication.java. Which line is that?

Comment: Hey Frank. Line 82 is in the snippet it's FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance() call

Comment: Use "@<name>" to reply to a specific person. Be sure you ping the right person, too. I'm not Frank. With that said, the error means that `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()` returns `null`. Maybe you are missing some configuration for it to work correctly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry for the mine mistake. And thank you for trying to help. Actually I do `FirebaseApp` initialisation before. Because In general Firebase and Crashlytics are work. For other millions of sessions. But only in rare cases crashes are present.

Comment: I added some changes in snapshot to show that `FirebaseApp.initializeApp` initialised before.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/crashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics#getInstance()):

> The default FirebaseApp instance must be initialized before this function is called. See FirebaseApp for more information.

So be sure you initialize the default `FirebaseApp` instance.